How to handle global monorepo dependencies when publishing to npm?
Imagine the following monorepo structure:
- package.json // Root level package.json with global `lodash` dependency
- packages
  - packageA
    - package.json // Uses global `lodash` but it is not listed in `dependencies`
  - packageB
  - ...

In my dev environemnt everything works just fine and packageA can see and use lodash listed in parent package.json.
But now let's suppose I want to publish packageA to npm.
It will be loaded to npm but lodash dependency is not listed in package.json (it is listed at top-level package.json which is not loaded to npm with packageA) so the package will break on client side!
How to tell npm that packageA uses lodash from parent package.json without specifying it directly in packageA's package.json file?
Because if I start writing lodash dependency in every sub-package it kind of eliminates the purpose of using monorepo plus it will be a hell to maintain the same version of dependency across all packages.

You cant. Thats not how it works. Either you write a Application that works as you designed it, or you write module that has dependencies. If your package A depends on lodash, it depends on lodash. How should npm handle that? From where should npm know that you package needs loadash if its not in the package.json of your Package A module? Whats the point of publishing a non working module to npm? npm was not designed for that. Perhaps "Peer Dependices" are what you are looking for
